# Is there a way to clone a tag of a specific git branch?

Tags: git, github

I want to clone a specific tag with specific branch from github. For example, there is a branch called `build` and I wanna clone from the branch `build` the specific tag `v1.0.0`. Is that possible with `git`?

I know I can clone either the tag or the branch by using something like:

```
$ git clone --branch v1.0.0 -build https://github.com/somerepro/app --single-branch --depth 1
```

But I would like to specify something like `--branch build --tag v1.0.0`. Is that possible?

Comment: The phrase *tag of a branch* is meaningless in Git. A tag represents one particular commit, by its hash ID, regardless of whether that commit is on zero branches, or one branch, or 1000 branches.

Comment: It really sounds like you just want to do `get fetch https://github.com/somerepro/app v1.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be two tags with the same name in one repo. It doesn't matter if the tag is on a branch or master.

Try checking out the branch then reset HEAD to the tag

```
git clone --branch build  https://github.com/somerepro/app --single-branch --depth 1
git reset --hard HEAD v1.0.0
```